# How to intercept the database file used by a Delphi application?

Tags: windows, delphi, reverse-engineering, windbg, portable-executable

I have entered data into a Delphi application for analysis, but the application exports the data into a messed up comma separated file (CSV). It does not export a database file.
I looked at the application binary and found out it is using SQLite3, given the linking symbols in its portable executable (PE).

Is there a way to find if the application is saving a file temporarily somewhere in my system?
If so, how to find it on Windows? Can I track files created by a process?

I would like to try anything before running the application and instrumenting the sqlite3_* function calls, since I don't know how to do that with WinDbg yet.

Comment: `Can I track files created by a process?` - you can use the Sysinternals tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) for this.

Comment: And when you found that file you can [(as per NTFS) deny the permission to delete files in that folder](https://superuser.com/a/720760/650342).

Comment: It is not necessary that the application is ever writing this database into a file. If this is some data analysis application it more likely that the database is stored in memory by using `TMemoryStream` as this allows much faster access to the data than if such data would be written on a disk.

Comment: @SilverWarior if its in the memory only, is there a way to export it?

Comment: It depends on which way it is stored in memory. If it is stored as file you may be able to find it as part of the application memory by searching for data representing file header. But it is more likely stored just ad database structure which means finding it will be a lot more difficult. Especially if this is relational database with multiple tables in which case each table might be stored in its own block of memory making extraction process extremely hard. Why not contact application developer and request ability to export data in other format besides CSV.

Comment: On the other hand many database management programs are pretty good at importing CSV structure into database. Have you already tried this route for reaching your goal. For instance [Import a CSV File Into an SQLite Table](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/)